# Simple class Property Update

Tags: python, class, oop

I have a class where I'm expecting this:

```
print(rithesh.amount) = 150.
```

How can I do this?

Here is my code:

```
class Customer:

    total_amount = 0

    def __init__(self, name, mob, email, amount=None):
        self.name = name
        self.mob = mob
        self.eamil = email

    def add_amount(self, amount):
        self.amount = amount

rithesh = Customer("Rithesh", "8896398598", "ritheshb1@gmail.com")
rithesh.add_amount(100)
rithesh.add_amount(50)
print(rithesh.amount)
```

Comment: change `=` to `+=`. or `self.amount = self.amount + amount`.

Comment: shouldnt your total_amount variable be called just amount? or else your add_amount method increment the total_amount value and then reference rithesh.total_amount?

Comment: declare `self.amount = 0` in `__init__`, and +=  in `add_amount`

Comment: @JaredSmith That wouldn't work unless the OP initialized `self.amount` beforehand.

Comment: `rithesh.add_amount(150)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can declare your amount variable in your `__init__` method as `0`. Then make a small change in your `add_amount` method.

```
class Customer:

    total_amount = 0

    def __init__(self, name, mob, email, amount=None):
        self.name = name
        self.mob = mob
        self.eamil = email
        self.amount = 0

    def add_amount(self, amount):
        self.amount += amount

    rithesh = Customer("Rithesh", "8896398598", "ritheshb1@gmail.com")
    rithesh.add_amount(100)
    rithesh.add_amount(50)
    print(rithesh.amount)
```

**output**

```
150
```

Answer (score 1):

The actual way of having properties in python is by using @property decorator

for example, in your class:

```
class Customer:

    total_amount = 0

    def __init__(self, name, mob, email, amount=None):
        self.name = name
        self.mob = mob
        self.eamil = email

    @property
    def add_amount(self):
        return  self.add_amount

    @add_amount.setter
    def add_amount(self, amount):
        self.add_amount = amount


rithesh = Customer("Rithesh", "8896398598", "ritheshb1@gmail.com")
rithesh.add_amount = 150
print(rithesh.add_amount)
```

Comment: this is for the property usage

Comment: Thanks man. But i want this as instance method. By declaring the value self.amount = 0 during initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Got how to do it.

i have to declare the value self.amount = 0 during initialization.

```
class Customer:

    total_amount = 0

    def __init__(self, name, mob, email, amount=None):
        self.name = name
        self.mob = mob
        self.eamil = email
        self.amount = 0

    def add_amount(self, amount):
        self.amount += amount

rithesh = Customer("Ritehsh", "8892398598", "ritheshb1@gmail.com")
rithesh.add_amount(100)
rithesh.add_amount(50)
print(rithesh.amount)
```

hence getting output as print(rithesh.amount) = 150

Comment: why are you answering your own question when arjit already answered it?

Comment: yes correct, for total calculation you are right. But if you need proper way of property usage, see below my answer

Answer (score -2):

What is happening is that when you call `add_amount` you are not adding the value to `self.amount` you are just setting it.

Just change the definition of `add_amount` from:

```
self.amount = amount
```

to:

```
self.amount += amount
```

And add to the `__init__` method:

```
self.amount = 0
```

Comment: Getting following error.    :   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rithesh B\Desktop\test321_simple - Copy.py", line 14, in <module>
    rithesh.add_amount(100)
  File "C:\Users\Rithesh B\Desktop\test321_simple - Copy.py", line 11, in add_amount
    self.amount += amount
AttributeError: 'Customer' object has no attribute 'amount'

Comment: This will not work because at the time `add_amount` is called, `self.amount` doesn't exit. So doing `self.amount += amount` will raise an `AttributeError`.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't looked at the ```__init__``` method. I was assuming ```self.amount``` had been initialized in ```__init__```.